# Why is my sql prepared statement not giving correct responses?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a login account system for my website and when a user registers, I check if there is already an account in the database. I created a function called 'check_user_exists' and here is the code for that

```
function check_account_exists($username, $conn){
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?")){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo $stmt->num_rows;
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        //couldn't prepare statement
        return false;
    }
}
```

However when I go run this it returns false every time even when I know that a value in the database already exists. I haven't had any MySQL errors before this but I checked the error log and it doesn't show any errors. I added `echo stmt->num_rows;` but it always outputs 0. What is the matter?

Comment: i'm testing if the $stmt was prepared correctly, not if $stmt's value was equal to the preparation of the sql.

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 in php you can declare variables inside if statements

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 it is confusing but it is practiced a lot

Comment: @blendy does the code work if you remove the if else statements?

Comment: so, now that this is settled, sorry @blendy for hijacking your question. the problem is, we can't really say what is the problem here. You need to enable error reporting, and get rid of that first if/else. it really does nothing. You shouldn't be verifying if prepares returns false, if there is an error, you should set mysqli so an exception is thrown.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Error logging does work. I get errors from typos and other mistakes all the time, but not from this code. The first if statement is correct because the code inside the if else block runs. I can verify because I put an echo statement inside the first if/else block and the echo runs.

Comment: well then, it means there are no users with the username you are trying to fetch.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I'm sure there are from that db table though

Comment: ... mysqli doesn't lie. Do an echo username to verify the input. If num rows says 0, it's because it's 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out I need to use `$stmt->store_result();` after `$stmt->execute();` That was preventing correct responses.

Comment: Ohhh.. right, I had unconsciously assumed the results were buffered, but indeed the results may not be accessible before you do that. Thanks for reminding me never to assume anything!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier This one really got me confused until I did a lot more research and just put that one line of code into my other function `login_check` and that fixed it. Because I was 100% sure that the SQL code was correct and that that DB table had that row in it. I even checked in phpMyAdmin and that showed the row. Strange that you need to do that but it makes sense. Thank you for your time and quick responses.